# JDBC MySQL Configure Username/Password Credentials Outside of Code

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

Is it possible to connect to a MySQL database without specifying the username and password in Java code:

```
Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("database url","username","password");
```

I want to be able to have my password in a private spot and call that password somehow in a safe manner. Any tips for this?

Comment: Use a connection pool managed by your web container. Or use environment variables to control the parameters. Or both.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to make a config file.
You can do it with librairies like Yaml (or Hocon for .conf files, ...):

```
YamlConfiguration.loadConfiguration(configFile);
```

Then get username, password (and even database URL) :

```
yamlConfig.getString("database.username"); // can be null if not registered in file
```

Comment: Or use a `java.util.Properties` file.